# iPhone - Distributing in-app purchases app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I want to integrate in-app purchases in my application. I want to distribute the app free of cost. I'll provide options inside the app to make in-app purchases. Can I distribute my application free of cost or do I've to sell my application for some initial price?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to distribute your app free of cost, check the iOS developer terms of use for the details.